# Writing unit test for wxPython

Tags: python, unit-testing, wxpython

I have an built app that contains a window made with wxPython that contains a text box to take inputs from the user, and the `enter` event is bound to a function and sends a wx.Frame object to it. The input value is accessed with `self.txt.GetValue()`

I need to write some unit tests for the function but cannot seem to find a way to create and pass an argument to the function in a way that the value will still be accessible with the same statement.

I also found a number of modules for testing python apps, including one on the wxPython page (pyunit), but the main intuition of HOW to pass the value is not clear.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you decouple the function from wxPython, you can easily unit test it. So let's say you have a widget bound to an event handler like this:

```
def on_text_change(self, event):
    my_module.do_something_with_text(self.txt.GetValue())
```

Now you can add a unit test for `my_module.do_something_with_text`  because it won't depend on wxPython.

If you want to create what amounts to an automated UI test, you can use UIActionSimulator - https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.UIActionSimulator.html

Comment: Thanks Mike! This is exactly what I had ended up doing, but left the question open in case anyone had a better workaround.

Comment: I forgot to mention this, but you could also use https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.UIActionSimulator.html to test the UI itself. I updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: BTW the UIActionSimulator Sample referred to at https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.UIActionSimulator.html is at https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/130e6693e10cd2af31f10da61724127ea9998020/samples/uiaction/uiaction.cpp

Comment: Thanks. That has moved around a bit over the years